# OSCommerce alternatives

Tags: e-commerce, oscommerce

I'm looking to evaluate a few opensource e-commerce solutions. Are there any good alternatives to OSCommerce out there ?

I've looked at Thelia and Magento so far, are there any others that are worth looking at ?

They should be :

- Free as in freedom
- Easy to maintain / extend
- Coded in PHP or Python (ideally, but I'm open-minded)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who may be interested, I ended up discovering and selecting PrestaShop.

It is coded in PHP/MySQL, highly configurable, very modular by design and the codebase is really clean and well-organized. A crapload of opensource and paying modules are available to extend the functionnality if needed.

Answer (score 2):

There are forks of OSCommerce such as [CRELoaded](http://www.creloaded.com/pages.php?pID=247&CDpath=179), although that doesn't change much in terms of the basic calculus, it just may have some additional features that you care about.

I had experience with CRELoaded/OSCommerce. I found the code base pretty bad, with UI and logic mixed in everywhere, with no good control over the architecture and what code goes where.

You said free as in freedom, so I'm going to throw this out (although I think the technology is Java). [Fry](http://www.fry.com/) is not at all free as in beer (several hundred thousand short of free), but whatever they implement you get full source code (at least according to their sales pitch when I was looking at them). I suspected that this was because they used GPL stuff in their stack, but I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

Another good one is [Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/), I have heard good things about both.  I also in the past used ClickCart Pro and it was nice a couple of years ago.

Answer (score 0):

zen cart

Very vague. Alternative in what way, in that they can also host products? Hav a CMS? Built in features? Configurable? Themable? What are you looking for?

Isn't this more of a google query?

Comment: Alternative as in "implements the same or an approaching set of features". Google won't give me feedback on the quality of the code or the ease of configuration.

Comment: Yes, but again. What. Features.? email management? payment gateway? click to enlarge? This is not a place to ask people to do your research for you. It's a place for you to provide some scope about what you are looking for that you can't provide in google. Your question CAN be asked of google
http://lmgtfy.com/?q=open%20source%20e-commerce%20feature%20comparison

Comment: I'm not asking people to do my research for me, I am asking to hear from people with hands-on experience with an e-commerce solution similar to OSCommerce. Yes, there are articles comparing e-commerce solutions on Google. Somehow, I thought there may have been a few helpful people on SO ready to share their experience.

Comment: Again, I'm sure if you narrow your question a little, I'm sure there are people ready to share. But it's not easy with such a broad scope as your question - something that can be google'd.

I've asked a number of times, what specifically are you talking about? So far, you haven't been any more clear about it.

Answer (score 0):

How about using opencart ?  It is released under GNU GPL